# Error whilst inheriting in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class RandomFleet : public PlaceFleet
{
```

This is my RandomFleet which needs to inherit from Placefleet. (this is in RandomFleet.h)

my error: invalid use of undefined type 'class Battleships::PlaceFleet'

I've included "PlaceFleet.h"
I've tried class Battleships::RandomFleet : public BattleShips::PlaceFleet

I can't figure out why it won't inherit properly.

**EDIT:** Also not PlaceFleet and RandomFleet both are part of 'Battleships' namepsace - I am not "using namespace Battleships" so I suspect this has something to do with it?

**EDIT WITH CODE:**

```
#ifndef PLACEFLEET_H_
#define PLACEFLEET_H_
#include"Place.h"
#include"Board.h"
class Battleships::PlaceFleet
{ //Functions and variables };
#endif
```

//above is PlaceFleet.h, below is RandomFleet.h

```
#ifndef RANDOMFLEET_H_
#define RANDOMFLEET_H_
#include"PlaceFleet.h"
class RandomFleet : public PlaceFleet
{//This is where compiler shows error
//Functions and variables
};
#endif
```

Comment: Have you actually *defined* the type `Battleships::PlaceFleet` in the `PlaceFleet.h` header, as opposed to simply *declaring* it?

Comment: I think we need a little more code.

Comment: I have declared it, the Battelships::Place fleet class seems to work fine. It was only when I tried to inherit it that I experienced problems.

Comment: Is the first bit of code (placefeet.h) a typo (I assume it is, but it's worth checking)... you aren't actually commenting out the closing `};` in the real code, right?

Comment: No that's just when I copy/pasted it

Comment: Make a minimal self-contained example. Keep expanding it until you can get it to fail in the same way, or else you discover where you are wrong. There's not enough here for anyone but you to go on further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I wasn't using

```
namespace Battleships
 {
   //classes here
 }
```

(I tried to do class Battleships::PlaceFleet)

Answer (score 2):

This is the template you should follow:

```
// PlaceFleet.h
#ifndef PLACEFLEET_H_
#define PLACEFLEET_H_

class PlaceFleet {

};

#endif

// RandomFleet.h
#ifndef RANDOMFLEET_H_
#define RANDOMFLEET_H_

#include "PlaceFleet.h"

class RandomFleet : public PlaceFleet {

};

#endif
```

Comment: except class Battleships::PlaceFleet { };

Comment: It should not be Battleships::PlaceFleet {};

Comment: Why not? Doesn't it need to be so the compiler knows it's part of Battleships namespace?

Comment: @RBowen - Did you actually write `class Battleships::PlaceFleet {};`?  Also, note that C++ is caase sensitive: you have typed both `Battleships` and `BattleShips` in this post and the comments

Comment: @RBowen - If you are within namespace Battleships, you do not need to prefix the class with the namespace name

Comment: I wrote Battleships::PlaceFleet (sorry for mistake before).

I'm not in Battleships namespace, that's in another file.

namespace Battleships
{
class PlaceFleet;//forward decleration
}

Comment: Then in PlaceFleet.h I've included "Battleships.h"

Comment: @RBo **A forward declaration *will not work here*. You need a complete definition of the class.** That's what the compiler error message is trying to tell you.

Comment: @CodyGray so how do I stop that? Take the forward declertation out of the Battleships namespace?

Comment: No. You need to provide a complete definition of the class to be inherited. The compiler can't *inherit* something that it doesn't have a complete definition for. That's what probably should be in the header file that shares the name of the class anyway.

Comment: in PlaceFleet.h? There is the entire definition, not a forward decleration

Comment: @RBowen can you post the entire code removing implementation details?

Comment: You can't first define a class using the Namespace::Class syntax. Use namespace Battleships{class RandomFleet;} to initially declare it to be in that namespace.

Comment: but I've got other classes in Battleships that worked fine with Battleships::className :S

Comment: `class RandomFleet : public Battleships::PlaceFleet {};` - does this fail?